# Finding the vertex of an elliptic cone

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, quadratic-forms

I have a elliptic cone

$$x^2 + (y - 4)^2 = (z - 4)^2$$

I know to solve for the vertex by setting each variable equal to zero, which gives $(0, 4, 4)$. I can see from the graph that this point is the vertex. But I only know this because I've seen an example of it being done. Can someone give a proper explanation on why this is the vertex?

Comment: Difficult question: how do *you* define the vertex of an elliptic cone? How do you define a cone in the first place? There are very different ways to think about it, depending on your mathematical background. Many people don't see an actual definition, from which you can prove/disprove things, of cones or their vertices. Some would identify a cone purely by its shape. Some would say a cone is defined by an equation of the form $(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 = (z - c)^2$ and the vertex is defined to be $(a, b, c)$. It would help to know what you, personally, understand what a cone and its vertex to be.

Comment: A cone is a quadratic surface defined by equation in your comment. I was just writing a detailed report and got hung up because I forgot why the vertex was what I knew it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mostly because there are (distinct) straight lines within the cone that all pass through the  vertex. These are lines parametrized by a new variable $t$
$$ (0, 4+t, 4+t)  $$

$$ (0, 4-t, 4+t)  $$

$$ (t, 4, 4+t)  $$

$$ (-t, 4, 4+t)  $$

For each one, at $t=0$  it goes through the vertex. The lines do not meet elsewhere.   To prove that for a pair, change the variable $t$ to $s$  in one of them, for example  $ (t, 4, 4+t) , \; \; (-s, 4, 4+s)  . \; \;   $  For the coordinates to match you need $t=-s$  but you also need $4+t=4+s. \;$ That happens only when $s=t=0$

using Pythagorean triples, we can find other lines (within the cone) without trig functions.

$$ (4t, 4+3t, 4+5t)  $$
$$ (5t, 4+12t, 4+13t)  $$
$$ (8t, 4+15t, 4+17t)  $$
$$ (20t, 4+21t, 4+29t)  $$